# Remove Unknown Number of Array Elements Starting at Specific Position

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am aware `pop()` will remove the last element in a JS array, and that `shift()` will remove the first one, and that `slice()` lets you remove elements from an array - and that you can specify what position to start at, and how many to remove, like so:

```js
let cities = ["New York", "Tokyo", "Perth", "Helsinki"];
cities.splice(2, 2);
console.log(cities);
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a method you can use to start at a certain array position, and remove any additional elements beyond that number?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, `splice`. Just do not provide the second argument

From [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> **deleteCount** *Optional*
>
> If deleteCount is omitted, or if its value is larger than array.length
>   - start (that is, if it is greater than the number of elements left in the array, starting at start), then all of the elements from start
>   through the end of the array will be deleted.

```js
let cities = ["New York", "Tokyo", "Perth", "Helsinki"];
cities.splice(2)

console.log(cities)
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Didn't realize this was an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just use splice provide the initial index only it will assume you want every other value till the end of the array

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change original array use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) by passing `0` as first argument

```js
let cities = ["New York", "Tokyo", "Perth", "Helsinki","Landon"];
let number = 1
console.log(cities.slice(0,number));
```

You can do that using `splice()` if you want to modify original array.

```js
let cities = ["New York", "Tokyo", "Perth", "Helsinki","Landon"];
let number = 1
cities.splice(number); 
console.log(cities);
```